# What should I store in my blob field?

Tags: sql, blob

I try to use blobs as little as possible. When possible I replace blobs by a link to a file. I can only think of a few times that I needed a blob. I used to put zipped pickled python objects in there, but I use mongo or couchdb these days for that. One thing I still use it for is to store wkb (gis) objects. This made me wonder, what do other people put in their blob fields?

Comment: zipped pickled python?  mongo?  You're ruining my appetite.

Comment: I heard mongo guisado is quite tasteful. 

[1] http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/mongo-guisado-mung-bean-soup/Detail.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[They have disadvantages...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211895/storing-documents-as-blobs-in-a-database-any-disadvantages), so tried to ignore them, especially now file-stream exists in SQL2008.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever binary data needs to be stored - typically images & documents (Word, PDF).

Comment: Binary serialized objects are another option.

Answer (score 1):

BLOB accepts any data, all the items stored in the BLOB are stored in whole disk pages in separate disk areas from normal row data. Normally in a BLOB you can store any data generated by your program, **images**, **graphics**, **video**, **audio** or **different types of documents**.