# Why does git store file contents as a blob?

Tags: git, blob

This question may seem trivial to answer, but I am struggling to come up with definitive advantages of storing file contents as blobs and not just its original format (e.g. a text file).

Typically, blobs are used in lieu of other storage formats for media: images, videos, audio, etc.  `git`, at least how I see it commonly used, typically tracks revisions to text files and not multimedia.

To summarize formally: what are the advantages of storing file contents as a blob (converts to binary data) rather than the original format of the revision (e.g. leave it as text)?

Comment: What do you mean by *original format of the revision*? File content whenever it text file or not is just a sequence of bytes. That sequence of bytes is called blob in Git.

Comment: A blob does store the original raw contents. That's what it means.

Comment: In Days of Yore (and still today), in the *database* world, entries in databases often had (have) types. Here, someone invented the term [*blob*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5414551/1256452) with the [backronym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym) Binary Large OBject, to mean "uninterpreted data". Linus Torvalds [stole](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1165624) the term for use in Git, but not quite with the same context. Note that Git stores other things as blobs as well, in particular the targets of symbolic links are stored as blob objects.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

“Blob” just means a sequence of bytes. A blob in Git will contain the same exact data as a file, it’s just that a blob is stored in the Git object database, and a file is stored on the filesystem.

So there is no difference in the format, the only difference is how they are stored.

For example, if you add an image `hello.jpg` to your repository, and then commit it, you will have two copies of the same data:

- You will have a *file* on disk, named `hello.jpg`, which contains the JPEG data,
- You will have a *blob* in your Git object database, named with the hash of its contents, which contains the *exact same* JPEG data in the same format.

The database can use some fancy tricks to store data efficiently, including compression and using deltas, but in the end it is still storing the exact same data that was in the original file.

A text file is no different. “Text” is just a particular type of data that you can store in a binary file.