# Load image from datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

Im trying to fill a `DataGridView` with the value coming from my database. There is one column that has a value of a `BLOB` or image. Now when I'm loading it to the `DataGridView` it shows an error: **Parameter is not valid**. Can someone help me about this?

**Triggering the method**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //load company to datagrid
        string company = "SELECT * from tbl_payroll_company";
        payroll.FillDataGrid(company, payroll_company_datagrid);

    }
```

**Method for filling my datagrid**

```
    public void FillDataGrid(string query,DataGridView gridview)
    {
        dbcon.Initialize();

        if (dbcon.OpenCon() == true)
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, dbcon.con);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            gridview.DataSource = dt;
            dbcon.con.Close();

        }

    }
```

**Here's how i saved it**

```
    private void btnCompanyUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog CompanyFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        if(CompanyFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                Image logo = Bitmap.FromFile(CompanyFileDialog.FileName);
                payroll_company_logo.Image = logo;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnCompanySave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            if(dbcon.OpenCon() == true)
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

                if (payroll_company_logo.Image != null)
                {
                    payroll_company_logo.Image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }

                byte[] logo = stream.ToArray();

                string[] column_name = {"payroll_company_logo"};
                string table = "tbl_payroll_company";
                string[] column_value = {logo.ToString()};

                dbcon.Insert(table,column_name,column_value);
            }

    }

    public void Insert(string table,string[] columns,string[] values)
    {
            this.Initialize();
            con.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO " + table + "(" + string.Join(",", columns) + ") VALUES('" + string.Join("','", values) + "')", con);
            int check = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();



    }
```

**ERROR**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show how those Images were stored? (A byte array which contains a Bitmap bytes, should be interpreted correctly by the DGV as it is).

Comment: @Jimi i edit my question and put the save code.

Comment: Store the byte array. [What is it exactly a BLOB in a DBMS context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414551/what-is-it-exactly-a-blob-in-a-dbms-context?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: I don't undrestand. But im storing it as a byte array.

Comment: You're storing a string in a BLOB field. See that your DB BLOB can store bytes (read what's in the link).

Comment: @Jimi thank you i change the way i inserted it it worked now.