# How to insert a html file in SQL table

Tags: sql, mariadb

What is the best way to store a html file in sql table and what is the sql query for the same ?

eg:
html file => index.html

`<h1>My HTML FILE</h1>`

This html file has to be stored in a column of the sql table.

Comment: 1) Define a column for your html, as varchar or BLOB, 2) Define a column so you can retrieve the row,  3) Optionally define another column for the filename (if needed), 4) "Insert" your data, 5) "Select".your row.  Easy Peasy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this as per your requirements:

1.Use your backend framework to open the respective HTML file and store the content of the file into DB as String.
E.g. in PHP [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp)

2.Use blob storage of the Database to Store the file directly.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414551/what-is-it-exactly-a-blob-in-a-dbms-context#:%7E:text=BLOB%20(Binary%20Large%20Object)%20is,allocates%20spaces%20in%20Giga%20Bytes.)

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with the below-mentioned steps

1. Change MySQL column to text or varchar according to the anticipated size of your HTML file
2. While saving HTML files escape all its HTML tags. This will prevent SQL Injection on your DB. Sample code for same in PHP is

`htmlentities($str);`

3. While fetching HTML from database run PHP's html_entity_decode() function on the html. Sample code for the same is

`html_entity_decode($str);`