# How to get past 65,535 size limit in node.js

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js

Can someone help me get past the 65,535 limit in node.js? I have it writing to a Microsoft SQL server database and I've tried the following data types for the RawJSON column: VarChar, Xml, VarChar('max'), and leaving it blank. It never writes the whole JSON to the destination column that is VARCHAR(MAX). Writing global.RawJSON to the console shows me that it is the full JSON.

```
// Dependencies
// { 
//   "name": "some function",
//   "version": "1.0.0",
//   "dependencies": {
//     "axios": "^0.18.0",
//     "fs": "0.0.1-security",
//     "mssql": "^6.3.1"
//   }
// }

const axios = require("axios"); // used to make http requests

async function getOrderDetails(orderCode, commerceUrl) 
  {
    const ordersUrl = commerceUrl + "/someCompany/orders/" + orderCode;

    console.log('ordersURL: ' + ordersUrl)

    const response = await axios.get
      (ordersUrl, 
        {
        headers: 
          {
            'x-b3-sampled': '1'
          },
        }
      ).catch(function (error) {
        console.error("error fetching order" + JSON.stringify(error))
      });
    return response.data;
  }


function getSqlConfig() 
  {
    return {
            user: process.env["SQL_USER"],
            password: process.env["SQL_PASSWORD"],
            server: process.env["SQL_SERVER"],
            database: process.env["SQL_DATABASE"],
          };
  }

function getOrderColumns(order) 
  {
    var billingAddressId = null
    if(order.paymentInfo && order.paymentInfo.billingAddress){
      billingAddressId = order.paymentInfo.billingAddress.id
    }
    return {
            code: order.code,
            RawJSON: RawJSON,
          };
  }

async function populateOrder(pool, order) {
  
  console.log('populateOrder start')
  
  var columns = getOrderColumns(order);
  
  var sql = require("mssql");

  try {
        await pool
          .request()
          .input("orderCode", sql.VarChar, columns.code)
          .input("RawJSON", sql.VarChar('max'), global.RawJSON)

          .input("source", sql.VarChar, "test 42")

          .query(
                "insert into SomeSchema.Orders \
                    (OrderCode,  RawJSON,  source) values \
                    (@orderCode, @RawJSON, @source) \
                    "
                );
    } catch (err) 
    {
      console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('populateOrder end')
}

async function main(event, context) {
  var sql = require("mssql");
  const commerceUrl = process.env["COMMERCE_GATEWAY_URL"];

  var orderCode = event.data.orderCode;
  
  if(event.extensions.request.query.id != null)
  {
    orderCode = event.extensions.request.query.id
  }


  var orderResult = await getOrderDetails(orderCode, commerceUrl);

  global.RawJSON = JSON.stringify(orderResult).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "")
 
  var config = getSqlConfig();
  try{
    var pool = await sql.connect(config)
    await populateOrder(pool, orderResult);
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    console.error(err)
    return "bad"
  }  

  return 'good';
}

module.exports = {
  main: main,
  getOrderColumns: getOrderColumns,
  populateOrder: populateOrder,
};
```

Comment: Why are you putting anything into `global.RawJSON`?  That's a clear anti-pattern and will absolutely fail if more than one user is ever using this code (like if it's in a server).  Data in a server should be passed in function arguments, or returned via return values or resolved values of promises, not stuffed into a global where it can conflict with other user's requests.

Comment: In fact, since the execution order of this code is not clear based on what you have posted, it's possible that your use of a global variable is leading to a timing problem where you're trying to use `global.RawJSON` BEFORE its value is in place.  You'd have to show the code that calls these functions you're exporting for us to see the rest of what is going on here.

Comment: Turned out to be an issue with SQL Server Management Studio only displaying only 65,535 characters in its output. Doing a Length on the string showed its actual size and I was able to save it to a text file and open it in Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

#### Not a Node.js limit

There is no such limit in Node.js. You are hitting a database limit.

You don't say what database you are using, but usually this calls for [a BLOB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5414567/675721). In Postgres, you may want to use the [JSON type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) instead. One could also argue that this whole value shouldn't be stored in a relational database at all, and would be better off in Redis or some other NoSQL solution, as many RDBMS don't handle large values very well.

#### Other issues.

As jfriend00 pointed out in the comments, there are other issues with the code. I guess we'll see you back here asking another question once you realize there's another problem!

Comment: Its writing to a Microsoft SQL Server database.

Comment: @ScottSchommer you should use BLOB then. If/when performance begins to degrades, consider adding a Redis server

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue with SQL Server Management Studio. It only displays 65,535 characters. Doing a Length on the column in SQL showed the true size and I was able to save it to a file and open it with Notepad++. Thanks to everyone for their help!

Comment: That's crazy. But why was it affecting your Node code?