# FILESTREAM storage in SqlServer -> MySQL equivalent?

Tags: mysql

Is there any equivalent in MySQL ver. 5.5 for FILESTREAM storage in SqlServer ?

Answer (score 3):

At the present moment, no. There's only `BLOB`, `CLOB`, etc. data types to store binary data in MySQL.