# understanding blobs and $_FILES

Tags: php, blob

I've read many articles on stackoverflow about this particular question, but I haven't seen one that explains it like I need it to be explained:

So I'm just trying to get a better understanding of using blobs and the $_FILES to insert and retrieve image files from a MySQLI database.

So far, I know that blobs are used for images, that they can be tiny/regular/medium/and large depending on the size.

I also know that $_FILES is used to get user file input like $_POST can be used to grab a username from a form.

I eventually want to get to the point where I can store a user-uploaded images into a database, and then display those images on the users profile.

Can someone give me any information on as how to do this?

Comment: Don't use blobs to store the files directly into the database. The best way is to put the filename in the database and store the file itself in a directory on your webserver.

Comment: @Joren how would I go about storing the file itself in a directory on the webserver(localhost). Up until now I've just been using MySQLI for all storage

Comment: best file upload tutorial i know: http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Here is a good link explaining to you the +/- of using database and/or filesystems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939049/storing-files-in-database-vs-file-system

Comment: [Here's another resource that might help.](http://google.com)