# Internal server error when uploading large files in php

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I'm using codeIgniter and I'm getting internal server error when trying to upload large files (might be 1Mb and up)
The file upload script is working because it uploads to the folder in the server. But saving the file into the database it doesn't work anymore. I've already tried changing the following but still doesn't work:

**php.ini**

- post_max_size = 50M
- upload_max_filesize = 20M

**my.ini**

- max_allowed_packet = 2048M
- max_execution_time = 150

Where else do I have to check to ensure that the file upload to the database works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the files do the directory, not on the database. You might want to save the path though in the databse.

If you want to know WHY, here are some previous post you should check.

1. [Storing Documents as Blobs in a Database - Any disadvantages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211895/storing-documents-as-blobs-in-a-database-any-disadvantages)
2. [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Comment: but the guy above me wants it saved into the database.

Comment: I second Eineki & Starx . Use any of the ajax based uploaders and save the path to db

Answer (score 0):

Restart your apache server and try again.

Comment: And how will this be possible to do on a shared server and other types of hosting plans?

Answer (score 0):

I think think you should save files to Database ..but if you insist try `NoSQL` Solutions instead .. such as `MongoDB` .. its faster and better